# Bootstrap 4.5.2 bug/update popper.js out-of-date new way is popperjs/core

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, popperjs

Co devs,

npm bootstrap 4.5.2 and up

It is not ready for @popperjs/core

I'm looking for someone to help me fix the bootstrap.js

as a temporary fix for

`ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'popper.js' in 'C:\Users\nodefion\Desktop\Website\Wordpress-Websites\Website-1\thema\wp-content\themes\Dolzon-2\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\js' @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js 7:101-121 @ ./src/app.js @ multi ./src/app.js ./src/app.scss`

Because npm I popper.js not work.

I can delete de  require('popper.js') in the bootstrap.js file

But I want to include the new @popperjs/core

without having to wait a month or 2 for the fix.

Share your thoughts with us

best regards,
Nodefion.com dev team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> still a temporary fix

But check out my Github on the bootstrap forum

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/31451